# Loading Google maps from inputs

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I was working on the example for google maps apiv3 http://briancray.com/posts/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api

But when i load the page after generating an API key i get the message as

`Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v2 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key`

If you see my code i have generated a key from Google maps for APi 3 version and also have indicated the same in the script tag.

What else should i do here to get this working ..thanks

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Extraction of Geocoding Data</title>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key=ABQIFI4V2HxQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxT29dNBGfxqMPq5zwdeiDSHEPL89A" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- According to the Google Maps API Terms of Service you are required display a Google map when using the Google Maps API. see: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html -->
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var geocoder, location1, location2;

      function initialize() {
          geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
      }

      function showLocation() {
          geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address1.value, function (response) {
              if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
              {
                  alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
              }
              else
              {
                  location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                  geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].address2.value, function (response) {
                      if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                      {
                          alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                          calculateDistance();
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
      }

      function calculateDistance()
      {
          try
          {
              var glatlng1 = new GLatLng(location1.lat, location1.lon);
              var glatlng2 = new GLatLng(location2.lat, location2.lon);
              var miledistance = glatlng1.distanceFrom(glatlng2, 3959).toFixed(1);
              var kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);

              document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<strong>Address 1: </strong>' + location1.address + '<br /><strong>Address 2: </strong>' + location2.address + '<br /><strong>Distance: </strong>' + miledistance + ' miles (or ' + kmdistance + ' kilometers)';
          }
          catch (error)
          {
              alert(error);
          }
      }

      </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">

      <form action="#" onsubmit="showLocation(); return false;">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="address1" value="Address 1" class="address_input" size="40" />
          <input type="text" name="address2" value="Address 2" class="address_input" size="40" />
          <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" />
        </p>
      </form>
      <p id="results"></p>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax to include Google maps Javascript v3 is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but for the above code i get no results but i do not get that message as indicated in the question..Any idea why

Comment: You've no result because your code is part of API v2, not API v3. Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for more informations.

Comment: K thanks..any examples for APIv3..Please let me know.Will go through the documentation

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/ contains many example of Google Maps API V3. Look a the source of one example to get the code. [This](http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html) is a Geocoding example.